# Use pandas to count empty cells or cells with specific text in a csv file

Tags: pandas, string, csv, count, is-empty

I'm trying to use pandas to:

1. read a csv file
2. count (in count1) values that contain the text "pending" in the column "Status_Issue" of the csv file
3. count (in count2) empty cells in the column "Status_Issue" of the csv file
4. sum the result of the first counting (count1) and the second counting (count2)

My code below does not produce any result. Could you please provide me some guidelines to correct my script:

```
    df = pd.read_csv("sortdata.csv")
    # function to count in the column Status_Issue number of Pending
    count1 = df["Status_Issue"].str.count("Pending")
    #function to count empty cell in the column "Status_Issue"
    count2 = df["Status_Issue"].isna().sum()
    # sum the number of pending in count1 and count2
    result1 = count1 + count2
```

Comment: do you get anything at all with your `df = pd.read_csv(...)` line? Your `usecols = ...` looks unnecessarily complex. What are you trying to do there? Is that working? I guess the core of my question is: Where does your code broke here? Since we don't have your csv, we can't run it and test it ourselves.

Comment: lambda x:x.lower() in ["Status_Issue"]  won't ever return anything

Answer (score 0):

To count empty cells in a specific column you can

```
df.column_name.isna().sum()
```

To count cells with a specific content you can filter the df first and then check its shape

```
df.query("column_name == 'specific_text'").shape[0]
```

In order to successfully read your .csv file you need to change the *usecols* argument, because currently the condition is never met, as string containing only lower letters won't ever equal "Status Issue"